# Webflux media stream through nginx sometimes fails

Tags: java, nginx, spring-webflux

Attempting to stream media files from a WebFlux application through Nginx I hit a strange edge where some videos don't work, but others work just fine.

The error I get sometimes is

```
 net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 206 (Partial Content)
```

The controller serving the media resource:

```
  @GetMapping(value = "/media", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
  public Mono<FileSystemResource> media(@RequestParam final String id) {

    return mediaFileService.findById(id).map(MediaFile::getPath).map(FileSystemResource::new);
  }
```

The default.conf configuration I've tried to run on Nginx

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name terrible-spa;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
  index index.html index.html;

  location /media {
        send_timeout 60m;

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;

        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Request_Uri_X $request_uri;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

        proxy_pass http://media-service:8080/media;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }
}
```

As you can see under the `/media` location point I've attempted most examples I can find around the internet for how to solve this. The big ones being `send_timeout` and `proxy_buffering`.

What I find strange is this only happens with some video files.

Is there any other configurations I can try? Or something obviously wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried `proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;`? Also, are you able to reproduce the issue without nginx at all? (And without wishing to be insulting - definitely not something silly like a permission issue on some of the video files?)

Comment: Cannot reproduce without Nginx in the mix; so its definitely something to do with that being there. Yeah I've also tried with `proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;`. Assuming that as things work without Nginx in the mix and some videos work, it isn't a permission issue as all files have the same :(

Comment: I suspected that was the case, but wanted to clarify - afraid my skillset lies firmly on the Java / webflux side rather than nginx so I'm likely unable to suggest much useful!

Comment: Awkwardly likewise... thanks for the suggestions though!